# Informs the APNS Feedback service about devices that deactivated notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The Feedback service of Apple's Push Notification service informs me about devices that have deleted my app. But will it also inform me about devices where the user deactivated the notifications altogether (for my app)?

Answer (score 0):

I just did some tests. The Feedback service is not informing me about devices that have push notifications deactivated.

Actually, thinking about the "issue", it makes sense. A user expects to receive Push Notifications as soon as she reactivated push notifications. Relaunching every app (so that the apps can reregister with their provider) would not be a logical action for the user to perform after activating push notifications.